# c# memory consumption the same, separate line for object/variable declaration vs not

Tags: c#, memory

I would like to confirm, that these two code segment, which are identical apart from formatted, consume the same amount of memory.

Writing differently but should create the same amount of object instances and therefore the same amount of memory?

**I'm looking for a link/article which 100% confirms this.**

```
if (message.MailMessageAttachments != null && message.MailMessageAttachments.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var mailMessageAttachment in message.MailMessageAttachments)
    {
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(
                new Attachment(
                        new MemoryStream(
                            mailMessageAttachment.Attachment.ToArray()),
                            mailMessageAttachment.Filename + mailMessageAttachment.Extension));
    }
}
```

and

```
if (message.MailMessageAttachments != null && message.MailMessageAttachments.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var mailMessageAttachment in message.MailMessageAttachments)
    {
        var btyeArray = mailMessageAttachment.Attachment.ToArray();
        var attachmentMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(btyeArray);
        var name = mailMessageAttachment.Filename + mailMessageAttachment.Extension;
        var attachment = new Attachment(attachmentMemoryStream, name);
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    }
}
```

Comment: profile the two options and find out for yourself.  Of course, I'd find it *extremely* unlikely that it would matter to your program even if there was a difference.

Comment: Look at the generated IL, If there is a difference in IL then use memory profiler. They should be same

Comment: "I'm looking for a link/article which 100% confirms this." good luck.  The compiler can optimize it however it sees fit, so there's no guarantee that ANY two different code bases will yield the same IL.

Comment: What's your end game here? Readability and maintainability are much more important than memory utilization 95% of the time.

Comment: @PaulAbbott end game? yes readability, Too often viewing other peoples code do I see the top one..., so I assume there must be a reason...(hence why I'm asking). I personally much proffer the latter, but want to confirm that there is actually no difference between the two. This is in general not specific to this code.

Answer (score 1):

"I would like to confirm, that these two code segment, which are identical apart from formatted, consume the same amount of memory."

These are not identical apart fro formatting. They are logically equivalent, but one stores intermediate values , the other does not.

If the question is - do they consume the same amount of memory at run time then the answer is probably yes. The storing of intermediate values that already exist probably doesnt add overhead. Many times people do this for debugging purposes.

Sounds like you are trying to win a code style argument with somebody

Comment: true your wording is better(ill try google it more with that), and yes its an argument  with myself. Do you perhaps have a link which out lines this and "probably yes", is not what I'm looking for. But this is along the lines of what I'm wanting to know.

Comment: you will not find a link that says - "this is so" because its bound to optimization strategies, but the variations will be trivial. The big message buffer byte array exists whether or not you store a reference to it. If you really want to know look at the generated IL